# Save PDF from PowerPoint (.pptx) with transparent background

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint, transparency

I am doing a presentation with Beamer and I want to use some pictures I've made for an old PowerPoint presentation.

The way I am doing it now is:

1. I put each figure in one slide, then I save the whole `.pptx` in `.pdf` format
2. I use `pdftk` to separate the slides in different files
3. I use `pdfcrop` for each of these files to trim the empty areas out

The problem is that I am putting these `.pdf` files in a document where the background is not white, and they were saved as white, not transparent

I've tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50069/how-to-change-white-background-of-an-included-pdf-to-transparent) with no success. Maybe there would be a built-in PowerPoint option or any other utilities for making it transparent since the `.pptx` conversion phase?

Comment: Does this help? [OfficeOne TransparentShow 3.0](http://officeone.mvps.org/transshow/transshow.html) - TransparentShow can make a particular color of the slide show transparent. The regions where the slides have the specified color are replaced by the contents on the desktop.

Comment: [so] duplicate [PPT to PNG with trasparent background](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5713676)

Comment: "The regions where the slides have the specified color are replaced **by the contents on the desktop**". It seems like a plugin only for presentations, not for exporting

Comment: You won't know till you try it ;). It does say "Click the Save Settings button to save the transparent color setting with the presentation itself." so it may work when exporting. In any case the [so] link should be looked at.

Comment: About the SO question, I guess the possible workarounds would be different depending on what file format you want. He asks for a ``.png`` conversion and that is what the answer delivers. I cannot do the same thing and get a ``.pdf`` or any other vectorized format

Comment: You can make a pdf out of multiple png files.

Comment: AFAIK once you convert a vectorized object to a raster image there is no way you can "recover" the previous quality, which is exactly the point of wanting a pdf

Comment: <shrug> time for you to do your own research.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found that selecting the figure and using the `Save As Image` approach detailed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7381929/293175) produced incorrect results when the output format is set to PDF (using Office for Mac 2016).

The workaround I found was to post-process the PDFs with Inkscape in the following way:

1. open the pdf in Inkscape
2. select everything with `Ctrl+a`
3. hit `Ctrl+Shift+g` repeatedly to ungroup the elements in the PDF
4. deselect everything
5. select the background layer and delete it
6. `Ctrl+s` to save the PDF again